# How to use php code in tpl file in collabtive in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, task-parallel-library

I need to use php code in tpl file in smarty. I used `{php} echo "hello"; {/php}`
But I need to use a smarty variable in php code.

For example I need to use following variable `{$myprojects[project].ID}` in following php code in index.tpl file

```
{php}
    $qry = "select name from tasklist WHERE project = ".{/php} { {php}$myprojects[project].ID {/php} } {php}." ";
    echo $qry;
{/php}
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you like to execute SQL query from within a template?!

Comment: My requirement is I need list of projects in tree view and its sub items would be their tasks at index.tpl

Comment: @user952044, the question still stands.  Don't do this in the template.

Comment: Consider how you might do this in your php doc and then pass it to Smarty to output.  That's the point, after all.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `$this` Smarty object in each template:

```
$this->get_template_vars('myprojects')
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to write your code like this

```
{php}
    $var = $this->get_template_vars('myprojects');
    // if it is not an array you can use directly and if it is an array use as below.
        $qry = "select name from tasklist WHERE project = ".$var['key'];
        echo $qry;
    {/php}
```

for your knowledge and better coding help see below

it is better you can create a class and call an object of class in you php file and develop a function to get desired output.

```
    $objMyF = new my_functions();
    $smarty->assign('objMyF',$objMyF);

    //and in your tpl file you can call its functions by
    {$objMyF->function_name($var)}
```